# How to store twitter search API tweets and retweet them

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am trying to use the twitter API post method to post a tweet that has been found using the get/search method. However, when I store the result of the search into the variable 'st' below, it doesn't work and always yields an error.

```
var st = "test" //This is where I want to store the tweet found by calling search. 

var params = {

q: 'hillary_clinton',
count: 1,
type: 'recent',
geocode: " 38.913376,-95.3352939, 3mi"
exclude_replies: true,
retweeted: false,

};

 T.get('search/tweets', params, gotData);

 function gotData(err, data, response) {
   var tweets = data.statuses;
   st = tweets[0].text // store the first search result in 'st'



 }

var tweet = {

  status: st

}

T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

function tweeted(err, data, response) {
 if (err) {
  console.log("It did not work")
  console.log(data)
  } else {
console.log("it worked")
}

}
```

However, when I run the program, the error always occurs (because it won't let me tweet duplicate tweets) - that means "st" is not being reassigned correctly like I want it to. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you search for tweets you are asking for the first 5 results back, so you always get those 5 results and keep setting `st` to the first tweet in that array of tweets.

You can do a couple of things.

Store the entire array as `st` and then loop through it to get the other tweets.

Use some of the api parameters on your next search like 'since_id'

> Returns results with an ID greater than (that is, more recent than) the specified ID. There are limits to the number of Tweets which can be accessed through the API. If the limit of Tweets has occured since the since_id, the since_id will be forced to the oldest ID available.

Check out some of the other parameters for the API,

[Twitter Search Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)

*of course, you could just wait for Hilary to tweet something new, shouldn't be too long of a wait...

Comment: I tried even just changing it to just returning 1 tweet, but it still wont accept the reassignment of st. I dont actually need more than one tweet. I just want to store one tweet found from the search method in 'st' and then tweet it myself using the post method.

Comment: can you log the tweets array and see other tweets? what happens if you set   st to tweets[1] ? is it different?

Comment: I just checked and it IS now successfully assigning st = tweet[0].text, but I still get an error when the "post" function is called and st is passed in as a parameter. It says the status is a duplicate, which I presume means it still thinks I am tweeting "test".

Comment: is the text the same every time? if so thats what I'm saying, you keep grabbing the same tweet over and over, try one time setting it to tweet[1].text and see if it give you the same error...